# Rails: Resource and Forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, resources, devise

*Preface: I'm not sure what resources are.*

I need this form (which is working from the `user/sign_up` route) to work on my 'offline page'--so users can still register when my app is down. My application_controller calls a `:filter_before, :except => [:offline]` and my registrations_controller has a `:skip_filter_before` action. (Is it called an action?)

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <p><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></p>
<% end %>
```

My Registration_controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :get_teams
  skip_filter :require_online
  def create
    build_resource

    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        respond_with resource, :location => redirect_location(resource_name, resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :inactive_signed_up, :reason => resource.inactive_message.to_s if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords(resource)
      respond_with_navigational(resource) { render_with_scope :new }
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Routes:

```
         confirm_account        /confirm_account(.:format)                {:controller=>"confirmations", :action=>"confirm_account"}
                 sign_up        /sign_up(.:format)                        {:action=>"sign_up", :controller=>"user/sign_up"}
        new_user_session GET    /user/sign_in(.:format)                   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
            user_session POST   /user/sign_in(.:format)                   {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
    destroy_user_session GET    /user/sign_out(.:format)                  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
           user_password POST   /user/password(.:format)                  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
       new_user_password GET    /user/password/new(.:format)              {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
      edit_user_password GET    /user/password/edit(.:format)             {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                         PUT    /user/password(.:format)                  {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
cancel_user_registration GET    /user/cancel(.:format)                    {:action=>"cancel", :controller=>"registrations"}
       user_registration POST   /user(.:format)                           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"registrations"}
   new_user_registration GET    /user/sign_up(.:format)                   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"registrations"}
  edit_user_registration GET    /user/edit(.:format)                      {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"registrations"}
                         PUT    /user(.:format)                           {:action=>"update", :controller=>"registrations"}
                         DELETE /user(.:format)                           {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"registrations"}
       user_confirmation POST   /user/confirmation(.:format)              {:action=>"create", :controller=>"confirmations"}
   new_user_confirmation GET    /user/confirmation/new(.:format)          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"confirmations"}
                         GET    /user/confirmation(.:format)              {:action=>"show", :controller=>"confirmations"}
             user_unlock POST   /user/unlock(.:format)                    {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/unlocks"}
         new_user_unlock GET    /user/unlock/new(.:format)                {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/unlocks"}
                         GET    /user/unlock(.:format)                    {:action=>"show", :controller=>"devise/unlocks"}
        editreject_admin GET    /admin/:id/editreject(.:format)           {:action=>"editreject", :controller=>"admin"}
            reject_admin GET    /admin/:id/reject(.:format)               {:action=>"reject", :controller=>"admin"}
            accept_admin GET    /admin/:id/accept(.:format)               {:action=>"accept", :controller=>"admin"}
     entries_admin_index GET    /admin/entries(.:format)                  {:action=>"entries", :controller=>"admin"}
 preferences_admin_index GET    /admin/preferences(.:format)              {:action=>"preferences", :controller=>"admin"}
             admin_index GET    /admin(.:format)                          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin"}
           about_entries GET    /entries/about(.:format)                  {:action=>"about", :controller=>"entries"}
             all_entries GET    /entries/all(.:format)                    {:action=>"all", :controller=>"entries"}
       myentries_entries GET    /entries/myentries(.:format)              {:action=>"myentries", :controller=>"entries"}
              rate_entry GET    /entries/:id/rate(.:format)               {:action=>"rate", :controller=>"entries"}
            submit_entry PUT    /entries/:id/submit(.:format)             {:action=>"submit", :controller=>"entries"}
          entry_comments POST   /entries/:entry_id/comments(.:format)     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"comments"}
           entry_comment DELETE /entries/:entry_id/comments/:id(.:format) {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"comments"}
                 entries GET    /entries(.:format)                        {:action=>"index", :controller=>"entries"}
                         POST   /entries(.:format)                        {:action=>"create", :controller=>"entries"}
               new_entry GET    /entries/new(.:format)                    {:action=>"new", :controller=>"entries"}
              edit_entry GET    /entries/:id/edit(.:format)               {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"entries"}
                   entry GET    /entries/:id(.:format)                    {:action=>"show", :controller=>"entries"}
                         PUT    /entries/:id(.:format)                    {:action=>"update", :controller=>"entries"}
                         DELETE /entries/:id(.:format)                    {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"entries"}
                                /auth/:service/callback(.:format)         {:controller=>"services", :action=>"create"}
                services GET    /services(.:format)                       {:action=>"index", :controller=>"services"}
                         POST   /services(.:format)                       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"services"}
                    root        /(.:format)                               {:controller=>"entries", :action=>"index"}
               countdown        /countdown(.:format)                      {:controller=>"application", :action=>"countdown"}
```

Comment: "Action" generally means a public method on a controller. `before_filter` settings are filters, and a `skip_before_filter` adjusts those settings.

Comment: Thanks, tadman. Do you know what I'm asking?  I guess the app either doesn't know how to route the form when it's submitted, or it can't find the resource...but again, I'm new to rails/programming. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'resource' in the case of Devise is what is actually being registered. In your case, it's most likely a User. However, User isn't hardcoded into Devise so that you can have multiple types of users, for example Admins or Editors. For the sake of simplicity in this case, when you read 'resource' think 'user'.

***The rest of my answer isn't really an answer, just a request for more details. I'll edit this with a proper answer if I'm able to help :)***

As for your question, I'm not 100% sure I understand what it is you're asking about. Are you trying to show the registration form on an offline page or trying to send the registration data to the offline page? In either case, are you receiving and error or such like preventing you from doing so? If you are, please post the error or details of the unexpected behaviour. Posting your routes.rb might also be helpful, depending on what your problem is.

Just one other thing I'm not clear on, is the offline page part of your rails app or hosted elsewhere? If the app is down, it won't be accessible.

**Update:**

So what I understand is you're trying to put the user registration form on an offline page? If so, try this.

In your controller:

```
def offline
  @user = User.new
end
```

In your offline.html.erb view:

```
    <%= form_for(@user, :url => user_registration_path) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>

      <p><%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.email_field :email %></p>
      <p><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></p>
    <% end %>
```

I don't think you have a route set up for your offline action, so you'll need to do that. For a quick and easy way, use something like this:

```
match '/offline' => "welcome#offline"
```

Where `welcome` is the name of the controller where your offline action is located.

Does this help any?

Comment: I'm trying to register from a page other than my default "sign_up" page. I don't think I'm trying to send the registration data to the offline page... See my update for my routes.

Comment: I've updated my answer, let me know if it helps or if I've misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on what `registration_path` is configured as, something you've defined in your routes but not explained here.

Also check the output of `rake routes` to see how it's interpreted in your environment. It would be prudent to check `log/development.log` to see how the form submission is being handled as the interpreted `params` are shown.

As to what `resource` is, does that come from Devise or your application?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's devise. Google returns mostly devise articles.  I understand that I probably need to fix my routes for this to work correctly, but I also need to get the resource thing figured out too, right?

Comment: Tadman, I appreciate you're support.  However, I'm still very confused--I was supposed to have this finished a few days ago and this is the only thing stumping me. If you can, could you please expand your answer a little more?

Comment: You could try re-tagging the question with `devise` and offering a bounty if it's important. I'm not as familiar with the internals of Devise to know for sure what's going on there.